# using passlib with argon2 gives MissingBackendError

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, password, encryption

1. Installed [passlib](https://pypi.org/project/passlib/) on my Windows 10 pc to study how to store passwords
2. To use passlib with argon2 I installed that [argon2-cffi](https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/) too just as it shows in the [passlib documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html?highlight=argon2#optional-libraries)
3. Runs fine on my laptop, I VNC to my RaspberryPi3B+ and install both of them and it gives me of errors

```
print(f"Execution time is: {timeit.timeit(setup= setup_code, stmt = statement, number = 1)}")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/timeit.py", line 233, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/timeit.py", line 177, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 7, in inner
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/passlib/handlers/argon2.py", line 664, in hash
    cls._stub_requires_backend()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2255, in _stub_requires_backend
    cls.set_backend()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2177, in set_backend
    raise default_error
passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: argon2: no backends available -- recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install argon2_cffi')
```

Comment: How did you install the backend? Did you install it for the correct python version? You would probably have to use pip3 to install it as the error msg shows you're using Python 3.

Comment: 1st i did as told in the [docs](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html?highlight=argon2#optional-libraries) 2nd I uninstalled both of them using pip and reinstalled using pip3 too  Thanks